# Attempt to reuse RNNCell with a different variable scope

Tags: tensorflow, rnn

I'm using Tensorflow 1.1.0 with GPU support and I have this function:

```
def get_init_cell(batch_size, rnn_size, keep_prob=0.75, layers=2):
    """
    Create an RNN Cell and initialize it.
    :param batch_size: Size of batches
    :param rnn_size: Size of RNNs
    :return: Tuple (cell, initialize state)
    """
    # Basic LSTM cell
    # lstm = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(rnn_size)
    lstm = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(rnn_size, forget_bias=0.0, state_is_tuple=True, reuse=tf.get_variable_scope().reuse)

    # Add drop to the cell
    drop = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(lstm, output_keep_prob=keep_prob)

    # Stack multiple LSTM layers
    rnn_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([drop for _ in range(layers)], state_is_tuple=True)

    # Getting an initial state of zeros
    initial_state = rnn_cell.zero_state(batch_size, tf.float32)

    # Set the name
    initial_state = tf.identity(initial_state, 'initial_state')

    return rnn_cell, initial_state
```

The previous code works perfectly with Tensorflow 1.0.0 if I use `lstm = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(rnn_size)` but now I have changed the way I get the lstm cell. And I get this error:

> ValueError: Attempt to reuse RNNCell
>    with a different variable scope than its
>   first use.  First use of cell was with scope
>   'rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/basic_lstm_cell', this attempt is with
>   scope 'rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_1/basic_lstm_cell'.  Please create a
>   new instance of the cell if you would like it to use a different set
>   of weights.  If before you were using:
>   MultiRNNCell([BasicLSTMCell(...)] * num_layers), change to:
>   MultiRNNCell([BasicLSTMCell(...) for _ in range(num_layers)]).  If
>   before you were using the same cell instance as both the forward and
>   reverse cell of a bidirectional RNN, simply create two instances (one
>   for forward, one for reverse).  In May 2017, we will start
>   transitioning this cell's behavior to use existing stored weights, if
>   any, when it is called with scope=None (which can lead to silent model
>   degradation, so this error will remain until then.)

I have changed `get_init_cell` with this one:

```
def lstm_cell(rnn_size, keep_prob=0.75):
    # Basic LSTM cell
    lstm = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(rnn_size, reuse=tf.get_variable_scope().reuse)

    # Add drop to the cell
    return tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(lstm, output_keep_prob=keep_prob)

def get_init_cell(batch_size, rnn_size, keep_prob=0.75, layers=2):
    """
    Create an RNN Cell and initialize it.
    :param batch_size: Size of batches
    :param rnn_size: Size of RNNs
    :return: Tuple (cell, initialize state)
    """    
    # Stack multiple LSTM layers
    rnn_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([lstm_cell(rnn_size, keep_prob) for _ in range(layers)])

    # Getting an initial state of zeros
    initial_state = rnn_cell.zero_state(batch_size, tf.float32)

    # Set the name
    initial_state = tf.identity(initial_state, 'initial_state')

    return rnn_cell, initial_state
```

And I still getting the same error.

I have also try it with the same error:

```
def get_init_cell(batch_size, rnn_size, keep_prob=0.75, layers=2):
    """
    Create an RNN Cell and initialize it.
    :param batch_size: Size of batches
    :param rnn_size: Size of RNNs
    :return: Tuple (cell, initialize state)
    """    

    def lstm_cell():
        # Basic LSTM cell
        return tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(rnn_size, reuse=tf.get_variable_scope().reuse)        

    def attn_cell():
        return tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(lstm_cell(), output_keep_prob=keep_prob)

    # Stack multiple LSTM layers
    rnn_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([attn_cell() for _ in range(layers)], state_is_tuple=True)

    # Getting an initial state of zeros
    initial_state = rnn_cell.zero_state(batch_size, tf.float32)

    # Set the name
    initial_state = tf.identity(initial_state, 'initial_state')

    return rnn_cell, initial_state
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you might be trying to use `MultiRNNCell` as a recurrent neural network. This isn't really its purpose; that is what dynamic_rnn, static_rnn, and raw_rnn are for. `MultiRNNCell` is intended for creating a feedforward, multilayer network which is the "cell" to be iterated to produce a recurrent neural network.

The old version of your code, if I understand it correctly, creates a network consisting of a sequence of LSTM layers, each with its own set of weights. If your goal is to make the weights shared between layers (so that your network is recurrent), you want to instantiate a `dynamic_rnn` and pass it a single instance of one of the RNNCell subclasses. That instance generates all of the layers of the network by having its `__call__` method invoked repeatedly, once for each layer. The `dynamic_rnn` instance handles the scoping and variable reuse issues for you and connects the layers together.

You have at least three options for the cell to pass to the `dynamic_rnn` constructor:

1) A `DropoutWrapper` which was created using a `BasicLSTMCell` (essentially, the output of **one** call to `attn_cell`, but get rid of that `reuse` option). Do this option.

2) A `MultiRNNCell` consisting of an LSTM layer, followed by a dropout layer (unneeded here, but this is what you would do in some more general case).

3) Subclass `rnn_cell` and create your own type of layer.